# How to return "Null" or an "Empty" object in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am currently writing a **Smart Contract** in **Solidity**. The smart contract, amongst other information, stores an array of properties object at the general level. The property object Looks like this:

```
    struct PropertyObj {
    string id;
    uint weiPrice;
    address owner;
}
```

Now there is a specific function that iterates over the array, finds the property and returns it (*code below*)

```
    function getPropertyByid(string memory _propertyId)private view returns(PropertyObj memory){
    for(uint i = 0; i<PropertyArray.length; i++){
        if (keccak256(bytes((PropertyArray[i].id))) == keccak256(bytes((_propertyId)))) {
            return PropertyArray[i];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The "Problem" is that, unlike other programming languages, Solidity does not allow to return null (*as far as I am concerned*).

In other words, if throughout the iteration we do not find the property, then what we shall return if we specified that we need to return ***PropertyObj memory*** in the function signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity does not have `null` value, as you're correctly stating.

Your function can throw an exception using the [revert()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/control-structures.html#revert) function.

It also seems that your implementation has a logical error. Your example would "return null" if the hash was not found during the first iteration. Instead, you may want to throw the exception after the loop has ended.

```
for(uint i = 0; i<PropertyArray.length; i++){
    if (keccak256(bytes((PropertyArray[i].id))) == keccak256(bytes((_propertyId)))) {
        return PropertyArray[i];
    }
}

revert('Not found');
```

---

Other option would be to return the empty object (with default values, i.e. zeros), if it fits your use case.

```
for(uint i = 0; i<PropertyArray.length; i++) {
    // ...
}

// not found, return empty `PropertyObj`
PropertyObj memory emptyPropertyObj;
return emptyPropertyObj;
```

Comment: Yes, you were right about where I return the "null", thanks for pointing it out :).
On the other hand, If I understand it correctly, there is no "default" way to return the  "null", but in my case, I could declare an "empty" object and return that instead.